# HMSegmentedControl Tying up the segmented control to a scroll view in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am using the popular HMSegmentedControl to present segments in my project. But I am facing a disastrous problem now that I am unable to tie my segments to a scroll view. As the example is in objective C. Its becoming difficult to do so in Swift. The code goes like this -

```
 self.segmentedControl4 = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 260, viewWidth, 50)];
self.segmentedControl4.sectionTitles = @[@"Worldwide", @"Local", @"Headlines"];
self.segmentedControl4.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
self.segmentedControl4.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.7 blue:0.7 alpha:1];
self.segmentedControl4.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
self.segmentedControl4.selectedTitleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:1]};
self.segmentedControl4.selectionIndicatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.3 alpha:1];
self.segmentedControl4.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleBox;
self.segmentedControl4.selectionIndicatorLocation = HMSegmentedControlSelectionIndicatorLocationUp;
self.segmentedControl4.tag = 3;

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[self.segmentedControl4 setIndexChangeBlock:^(NSInteger index)
{
    [weakSelf.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(viewWidth * index, 0, viewWidth, 200) animated:YES];
}];

[self.view addSubview:self.segmentedControl4];

self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 310, viewWidth, 210)];
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.7 blue:0.7 alpha:1];
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(viewWidth * 3, 200);
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(viewWidth, 0, viewWidth, 200) animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

Can anyone who has worked on this third party give me some solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for scrolling a segmented control. You can also download the source from [here](https://github.com/popodidi/HSegmentControl).

```
import UIKit
import HSegmentControl

class ViewController: UIViewController, HSegmentControlDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: HSegmentControl!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        segmentControl.dataSource = self
        segmentControl.numberOfDisplayedSegments = 3
        segmentControl.segmentIndicatorViewContentMode = UIViewContentMode.bottom
//        segmentControl.selectedTitleFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
        segmentControl.selectedTitleColor = UIColor.white
//        segmentControl.unselectedTitleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
//        segmentControl.unselectedTitleColor = UIColor.darkGray
//        segmentControl.segmentIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "ind_img")
        segmentControl.segmentIndicatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 31.0/255.0, green: 48.0/255.0, blue: 93.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        segmentControl.selectedIndex = 2
    }

    // MARK: - HSegmentControlDataSource protocol
    func numberOfSegments(_ segmentControl: HSegmentControl) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func segmentControl(_ segmentControl: HSegmentControl, titleOfIndex index: Int) -> String {
        return ["Kavin","Sitharth", "Raj", "Selva", "Rajesh"][index]
    }

    func segmentControl(_ segmentControl: HSegmentControl, segmentBackgroundViewOfIndex index: Int) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
//        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(drand48()), green: CGFloat(drand48()), blue: CGFloat(drand48()), alpha: 1)
        return view
    }

    @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("value did change to \((sender as! HSegmentControl).selectedIndex)")
    }
}
```

Comment: OutStanding working for me.......

Answer (score 0):

Just set up the segmented control normally and set the indexChangeBlock to scroll the scroll view:

```
segmentedControl4.indexChangeBlock = {
    let frame = CGRectMake(viewWidth * index, 0, viewWidth, 200)
    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated:true)
}
```

This will scroll the scroll view every time the segmented control's index changes.

Comment: But now the problem is coming about having the view resized as per landscape because the scroll view is taking its width from the self.view.width. which is not the same in the case of landscape...please suggest something.

Comment: Instead of using `viewWidth`, just get the current width of the scroll view, in whatever orientation it's in.

Comment: I have a VC(eg.VC1) embedded in a Nav.Controller whose view I add in the scroll view. Now I have a button in VC1 which is connected via segue to VC2. Problem is doing so,when I click on the button and move to VC2 the navigation bar hides in the VC2. How to show the nav.bar in the VC2?